# C read file in byte chunks

Tags: c, unix

Could not find proper documentation on this but I am trying to read a file using *nix system call read(). And I want read the file in 1024 byte chunks. Not sure what I have below is correct or not:

```
while (read(fd, buffer+i, 1024) == 1){
            i++;
}
```

Can someone please verify?

Comment: `man read` not working for you?

Comment: @John3136 My man left me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you can't use `man`, why not just search for [it](http://man.he.net/?topic=read&section=all)?

Anyway you are using it wrong. If you want to read it by chunks you should do it like this

```
// consider that we allocated enough memory for buffer
// and buffer is byte array
ssize_t r = 0, i = 0;
do {
  r = read( fd, buffer + i, 1024 ); // try to read 1024 bytes
  i += r; 
} while( r > 0 );
```