# Text file: Read 64 bits at a time

Tags: c, file, chunks

I need to write a C program where I have to implement (TEA) Tiny Encryption Algorithm using CBC (Cipher Block Chaining).

TEA takes 64 bit block and encrypt it using 128 bit key. CBC explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).

How can I read a text file 64 bits at a time?
How to fill the block with 0s?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C read file in byte chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290400/c-read-file-in-byte-chunks)

Comment: Most practical systems use 8-bit bytes, so 64 bits corresponds to 8 bytes.  Hence, read the file in chunks of some multiple of 8 bytes (1024, or 4096 perhaps), and then encrypt 8-byte (64-bit) blocks and chain the results appropriately.  Don't forget to pad the file appropriately using a deterministic algorithm to do that padding (PKCS #7, for example).  You can use `memset()` to zero a block of data.